# is there a Pull command in apify-cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, cheerio, apify

As I see , in the documentation of Apify-cli in this link :
https://docs.apify.com/cli

There is a command to push a local code source to a remote one (Apify cloud) .

is there a command for the inverse action , from Apify cloud to local , (Like pull command in Git ) ?

or I must do it manually by copy paste?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can't pull it from the platform, you need to manually download it by clicking the "Download source code" (in case of the multiple file editor)

[image]

or copying the text from the single file editor

[image]